# What is a default transaction isolation level in sqlalchemy for Postgres?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I use sqlalchemy for Postgres DB.

```
engine = create_engine(
    "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/test"

...
```

Create engine without Postgres dialect(psycopg2, pg8000, or other). So my question: what is a default transaction isolation level? And what is a default Postgres dialect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#postgresql), the default postgres driver used by SQLAlchemy is psycopg2.

The default transaction isolation level is configured on the DB side, not by the client. Out-of-the-box, [it is READ COMMITTED](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DEFAULT-TRANSACTION-ISOLATION).